# How to get all records for the entire day?

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

I have some records and I only want to show that day so if it is July 6th it should be

```
7/6/2011 12:00:00 AM to 7/6/2011 11:59:59 AM
```

Say I have a record that has a due date of July 6th 7pm (my local time)

```
07:00:00 p.m. Wednesday July 6, 2011 in Canada/Pacific converts to
02:00:00 a.m. Thursday July 7, 2011 in UTC
```

That is 2am UTC time. This is stored in the database(I store only UTC dates and then use UTC to grab records I need then convert to local time zone)

Now I have this code

```
    DateTime startDate = DateTime.UtcNow.Date;


    DateTime endDate = DateTime.UtcNow.Date.AddSeconds(86399);

    return new DateFilterRange(startDate, endDate);

// result
7/6/2011 12:00:00 AM to 7/6/2011 11:59:59 AM
```

Of course this does not grab the above task because in the db the record is stored as July 7th but the user is still in July 6th.

I am thinking I have to use the offset some how but I am not how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: I'm assuming you already know the users time zone, based on comments...

1 get "right now".
2 convert to user's time zone.
3 get day boundaries in user's time zone.
4 convert boundaries to UTC time.

```
DateTime userDayStart = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(
    DateTime.UtcNow,
    usersTimeZone
).Date;

DateTime utcStart = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(
    userDayStart,
    usersTimeZone
);

DateTime utcEnd = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(
    userDayStart.AddDays(1),
    usersTimeZone
);
```

Of course, the .Date and .AddDays() operations happen in the local time zone, so it won't be perfect with regard to daylight savings time etc.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you need to take your local time boundaries, e.g. the start of the local day, convert those to UTC, and then filter by that.

Note that your initial example only shows the first half of July 6th - 12am to 12pm. It's not clear whether that's what you want.

Be aware that in some time zones, not all days start at midnight - if a DST change occurs when midnight *would* occur, the day may actually start at 1am.

EDIT: Just to be clear...

You need to get year, month and day from the user somehow. If that's specified in the UI, you can use this code:

```
DateTime localDate = new DateTime(year, month, day, 0, 0, 0,
                                  DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
```

Otherwise, you'll want something like:

```
// Work out the current date in the *user's* time zone
DateTime localDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.UtcNow, timeZone).Date;

// And then convert that "start of day" back to UTC
DateTime utcStart = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(localDate, timeZone);
DateTime utcEnd = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(localDate.AddDays(1),
                                                timeZone);
```

Note that this *doesn't* take into account time zones where midnight doesn't always happen.

Comment: Sorry the timezone stuff is confusing the heck out of me. I want everything that falls in their day. So if they are on July 6th and the task falls in July 6th show. If not don't show. I did to July 7th because I know with like ical stuff they go right to midnight of the next day to make the full 24 hours. So I thought I should try that as well. I am not sure how to get the start of the local day though.

Comment: @chobo2: Take the *local* midnight (e.g. `DateTime.Now.Date`) and convert that to UTC. Then also take the local midnight of tomorrow (e.g. `DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(1)`) and convert that to UTC. That gives you the boundaries. (And yes, it's all confusing - I hope to make things a bit better when I get to work on Noda Time a bit more...)

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that this is a website(asp.net mvc 3) and DateTime.Now will give me the server time not the users local time.

Comment: You'll have to get the local time somehow, here is one method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228926/finding-browser-local-time-in-asp-net

Comment: @kscott  - I need it before the page loads up so javascript is not the way to go. To bad their is not a DateTime.Now that you can pass in the users timezone in

Comment: If you're using .net 4.0 or later, you can use TimeZoneInfo class.  (mvc 3 appears to require .net 4, so you should be good to go)

Comment: @ebyrob  -I am using TimeZoneInfo class for other things but not sure how to combine it with what I have to get what I want. Doing UTC to Local time then going back again I don't think will get me anywhere.

Comment: @chobo2: It's awkward, to be honest... but constructing a local time  and then using `TimeZoneInfo` should do the right thing, I believe.

Comment: @ Jon Skeet - how do I construct the local time? I don't know their local time really and if I use datetime.utc.now then convert to local time and then back to utc(cuz all the dates are in utc in db) won't I just be back at square 1?

Comment: @chorbo2: No, you use `DateTime.Today` to get the local date, but convert it into a UTC date (or `DateTimeOffet`) using *their* time zone.

Comment: @Jon Skeet- But won't DateTime.Today get me the servers time not the local time of the users?

Comment: @chobo2: Well, it gets a "local" DateTime. You need to create one with a kind of "unspecified" to allow TimeZoneInfo to work properly. See my example code. As I said, the .NET types are a mess...

Comment: I think the 17:44 edit will pick the wrong day in cases where local (server) day and user day differ.

Comment: @Jon Skeet - but if the server is like in the U.S and my user is in the UK won't the times till be wrong? if going off the server time?

Comment: @ebyrob: Yes, you're right. Will edit. @chobo2: The times won't be wrong, but the date might be - editing.